# c# drop down list selected count

Tags: c#-2.0

yesterday i asked one question and got the answer from our friend here, and i ran successfully, also it have one problem with it. "Yester day My question is, when we selecting the drop down list then it should be shown by a label as "1" at very first time, again it'll be increas by selection", this is what the answer i got..,

```
static int count = 0;
private void bind()
{ 
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ar.Add("first"); 
    ar.Add("Second");
    ar.Add("Third");
    ar.Add("Four");
    ar.Add("Five");
    ar.Add("Six"); 
    ar.Add("Seven");
    CCddl.DataSource = ar;
    CCddl.DataBind();
}

protected void CCddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count == 0) count = 1;
        Label12.Text = count++.ToString(); 
}
```

this code worked, but once the running window getting closed, then it lose the continuation, i mean again application getting run it'll shown again "1". But exactly what i want is, the number continuation should be end when the system day has change.

Comment: So you are wanting to perserve state between form openings, resetting only on change of day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh(v=vs.80).aspx) feature.  I added two user settings `CountDate` and `Count` in the Project->Property's->Settings and changed your SelectedIndexChangedEvent to

```
protected void CCddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count == 0) count = 1;
        Label12.Text = count++.ToString();

    Properties.Settings.Default.CountDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Count = count;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

And right before you call your `Bind` Method during your form initialization put something like this.

```
 if(Properties.Settings.Default.CountDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
 {
    Properties.Settings.Default.Count = 0;
    Properties.Settings.Default.CountDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
 }
 else
    count = Properties.Settings.Default.Count;

 bind();
```

---

Added the Property Settings Image

[image]

Comment: i cant able to add the countdate and count sir, i cant get the path as you said,.. if you dont mind please explain me.. ANd my version is Visual Studio2005

Comment: @AravindSai it was first available in VS2005 I adjusted the link to point to the right MSDN Page. to get where you need to go you need to right click on your project and select properties and go to the Settings section it should look similar to the Image I posted.

Comment: @AravindSai Look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=VS.80).aspx) it looks like it has the information all in one spot.

Comment: Sir, i was created sir but i cant get the methods, as you have used in your code

Comment: @AravindSai According to the last link I posted, it should work. You should have a Properties Class. Try putting your Application Name in front of the Properties, In the case of my example it would be `WindowsFormsApplication29.Properties.Settings.Default.Count` Also look at this [CodePlex Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow store the value in a database or something. With the date value. Then when the datechanges you just reset the value.